# Easier way to reserve port number in C

Tags: c, sockets

Hi I'm wondering if there is an easier way to check if a port number is available and i suppose reserve it so i can use it up ahead? The below code works in doing just that but it seems over complicated.

```
 int getSocketNo(){
socklen_t namelen;
struct sockaddr_in node;
int sock_1;

/* ----Address information for use with bind---- */
node.sin_family = AF_INET;         /* it is an IP address */
node.sin_port   = 0;
node.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; /* use any interface on this host*/

/* ----Create TCP/IP socket---- */
sock_1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sock_1 == -1) {
    perror("socket() Socket was not created");
    exit(-1);
}

while(1){
    /* ----Bind socket to address and port---- */
    if (bind(sock_1, (struct sockaddr *) &node, sizeof(node))) {
        perror("Server bind error");
        continue;
    }

    int y = 1; // not sure what this does yet
    setsockopt(sock_1, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &y, sizeof(y));

    /* ----Find out what port number was assigned---- */
    namelen = sizeof(node);
    if (getsockname(sock_1, (struct sockaddr *) &node, &namelen)) {
        perror("Server get port number");
        exit(-1);
    }
    close(sock_1);
    break;
}

return ntohs(node.sin_port);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing everything right except for closing the socket. Don't close it: return the *socket.* Otherwise you're just opening another timing window during which the port can be grabbed by something else.

Looping while `bind()` fails is pointless. The whole thing is pointless really. You're specifying a zero port, so you're going to get a system-allocated one, unless the port space is exhausted. This is what you should do *when creating the socket you need.* There's no point in creating *another* socket just to try to 'reserve' a port. The way to reserve a port is to create the socket that you need.

Answer (score 1):

**Reserving Port Numner:**

You can not reserve port numbers for a program/app before hand. `bind()` does what you want. *It reserves the port number for the process which has called bind for the port number.*

---

**Checking If Port Number Is Available:**

As far as checking if the port number is available, the answer again is `bind()`. `If the port number is not available, bind will fail`. This means the port is being used by some other process. Try binding a new port number

*For more info:* **[Linux Man](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind)**

---

**Easy Sample Code:**

```
int main()
{
int sockFd, bytesRead = 1, bytesSent;

char buffer[MaxBufferLength];

struct sockaddr_in server, client;


server.sin_port= htons(PORT);
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

sockFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);


if(sockFd < 0)
    printf("Unable to open socket\n");


int i = bind(sockFd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

if(i < 0)
    perror("Unable to bind\n");



i = listen(sockFd, 1);

if(i < 0)
    printf("Unable to listen\n");


int len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);

int connectionSocket = accept(sockFd, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &len);

if(connectionSocket < 0)
    perror("connection not established\n");


   // from this point onwards, send & receive data.
```